# LED indication for driven n-FET inputs

Tags: led, circuit-design, fet, topology

Given that I'm using a microcontroller (e.g. an ATtiny85) output pin to drive the gate of an n-channel FET (e.g. NTMD6N02R2G) acting in the role of an SPST switch, is there any issue with either of the following two circuit topologies?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6yJGb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R4 in these circuits is intended to provide a 'default' state before the MCU powers up and configures the GPIO pins as outputs (so the FET gates are never floating). Will these topologies work in general given I'm using logic-level FETs? I understand that there will be some small wasted current drawn through R1 / R4 when the gpio pin is in the 'active' state.

Comment: Circuit 1 will enable the MOSFET if the MCU is in reset. Is this what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

The first schematic will not work as intended. The forward voltage of the LED dominates the gate voltage, so different LED colors will produce different gate voltages and some combinations of LED and FET will produce very different load currents from 0 to 5 mA.

The current will also be temperature dependent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBLU2w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The LED forward voltage might be 2 volts or, it might be 3 volts. Either way, the gate voltage won't be affected because of the resistor in series with the LED.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, if the MCU output is enabled, but as I understood the question, the behaviour during disabled port at MCU power up was asked for.

Comment: yes you are quite correct.